# Square of a number being defined using #define

Tags: c

I was just going through certain code which are frequently asked in interviews. I came up with certain questions, if anyone can help me regarding this?

I am totally confused on this now,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define square(x) x*x

main()
{
      int i, j;
      i = 4/square(4);
      j = 64/square(4);
      printf("\n %d", i);
      printf("\n %d", j);
      printf("\n %d", square(4));
      getch();
}
```

The output is:

```
 4
 64
 16
```

I am wondering, why did `square(4)` return 1 when I divided it? I mean, how can I get the value **4 and 64** when I divide it, but when used directly I get **16**!!?

Comment: Just to note that #define square(x) x*x is a clasic C baddy. Try a loop with square(x++);

Comment: If you really want to confuse yourself and you haven't read any of the answers yet, try replacing `square(4)` everywhere with `square(3+1)`.

Comment: This was a simple precedence problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`square` is under-parenthesized: it expands textually, so

```
#define square(x) x*x
   ...
i=4/square(4);
```

**means**

```
i=4/4*4;
```

which groups as `(4/4) * 4`.  To fix, add parentheses:

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Still a very iffy `#define` as it evaluates `x` twice, so `square(somefun())` calls the function twice and does *not* therefore necessarily compute a square but rather the product of the two successive calls, of course;-).

Comment: +1 for `square(somefun())`. The usual observation in that case is about side effect done twice, but if you imagine `square(rand())` you are getting the product of two random numbers, not the square of a single random number.

Comment: Also consider `square(n++)` which is UB. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76719135/480982

Answer (score 5):

When you write `i=4/square(4)`, the preprocessor expands that to `i = 4 / 4 * 4`.
Because C groups operations from left to right, the compiler interprets that as `i = (4 / 4) * 4`, which is equivalent to `1 * 4`.

You need to add parentheses, like this:

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

This way, `i=4/square(4)` turns into `i = 4 / ((4) * (4))`.
You need the additional parentheses around `x` in case you write `square(1 + 1)`, which would otherwise turn into `1 + 1 * 1 + 1`, which is evaluated as `1 + (1 * 1) + 1`, or `3`.

Answer (score 4):

```
i=4/square(4);
```

expands to

```
i=4/4*4;
```

which equivalent to

```
i=(4/4)*4;
```

Answer (score 3):

Operator precedence is hurting you.

The macro is expanded by the pre-processor such that

```
  i=4/4*4;
  j=64/4*4;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
  i=(4/4)*4;
  j=(64/4)*4;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the compiler replaces it with:

```
i=4/4*4; 
j=64/4*4;
```

i = (4/4)*4 = 1*4 = 4.

j = (64/4)*4 = 16*4 = 64.

Answer (score 2):

`j = 4/square(4) == 4/4*4 == 1*4 == 4`

Answer (score 1):

Manually expand the macro in the code, and it will be clear. That is, replace all the square(x) with exactly x*x, in particular don't add any parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

define is just a text macro

```
main()
{
      int i,j;
      i=4/ 4 * 4;  // 1 * 4
      j=64/4 * 4; // 16 * 4
      printf("\n %d",i);
      printf("\n %d",j);
      printf("\n %d",square(4));
      getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a macro! So it returns *exactly* what it substitutes.

```
i = 4/4*4;   Which is 4...
j = 64/4*4;   Which is 16...
```

Try this for your macro:

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of operator precedence in the expression after the preprocessor - you'll need to write

```
#define square(x) (x*x)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, you're getting burned by operator precedence.  Change your square macro to this:

```
#define square(x) (x*x)
```

and it'll work the way you expect.