# Incorrect multiplication of integers in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

A C-coded S-function in Simulink was showing incorrect behaviour and I have managed to narrow down the problem to an incorrect multiplication of integers.

At the start of the code, I have something like:

```
#define NRBF       21
#define NRBF1  NRBF+1
```

Then, in a function in the script I have:

```
void function_name(SimStruct *S, const int_T a)
{
...
    int_T base;
    base = a*NRBF1;
    printf("%i\t", a);
    printf("%i\t", NRBF1);
    printf("%i\n", base);
..
}
```

Now, if `a=0`, `NRBF=21`, I have (instead of `base=0`)

```
0  22  1
```

If `a=1`, `NRBF=21`, I have (as expected `base=22`)

```
1  22  22
```

If `a=2`, `NRBF=21`, I have (instead of `base=44`)

```
2  22  43
```

Now, I must say I am a bit baffled. I tried to change the line of the multiplication to

```
base = a* (int_T)NRBF1;
```

but it does not solve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `a*NRBF1` expands to `a*21+1`. Use parentheses as in `#define NRBF1  (NRBF+1)`

Comment: duplicate candidate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719150/square-of-a-number-being-defined-using-define. There are probably others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

You define your macros like this:

```
#define NRBF       21
#define NRBF1  NRBF+1
```

When you write this:

```
base = a*NRBF1;
```

The preprocessor replaces `NRBF1` textually with `21+1` which results in this:

```
base = a*21+1;
```

but you intended this:

```
base = a*(21+1);
```

Therefore you need to define your macro like this:

```
#define NRBF1  (NRBF+1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are absolutely right. That was silly of me.

Answer (score 3):

With the macro expanded, the line looks like:

```
base = a*NRBF+1;
```

- For `a` equal to 0, the expression is `0 * 21 + 1` which is 1.
- For `a` equal to 2, the expression is `2 * 21 + 1` which is 43.

The solution is to put parentheses in the macro definition:

```
#define NRBF1 (NRBF + 1)
```

This is a good rule for any macro with an expression as its right-hand side.

Remember that macros are just text-substituted into the code.

Comment: the expression results to `43`, if `a` equals to `2`.

Comment: @mch Thanks, corrected. Pre-coffee small-integer arithmetic is nothing for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

It's basically calculating alright

```
0*21+1 = 1
```

The macro is expanded but the `*` has precedence over `+`. That's why this happens.

A more detail explanation would be

```
#define NRBF       21
#define NRBF1  NRBF+1
```

So what is going on

```
base = a*NRBF1;
```

or

```
base = a*NRBF+1

Now when a = 0 then base = 1
    when a = 1 then base = 21+1 ...so on.
```

Correct way would be to wrap it aropund parentheses.

```
#define NRBF1  (NRBF+1)
```

---

Some more pitfalls:

That when you add a macro like this `#define SQR(X) X*X`

For some example like this where same precedence operators are there next to next then it will be problematic.

```
int i = 100/SQR(10);
```

Then it will be expanded to

```
int i = 100/10*10
```

Now same precedence operators are here executed left to right.

So it will result in `i=100`.

Solution same `#define SQR(X) (X*X)`

Also when passing an expression like this `SQR(i+1)` then it will be expanded to `i+1*i+1`=`2*i+1`. So a bit more correct would be

```
#define SQR(X) ((X)*(X))
```

Even with that you wouldn't be able to avoid few things if you forget one thing *macro just expands - it does nothing more*.

You can't use macro like this

`SQR(i++)` which will be expanded to `((i++)*(i++))`. So you are increasing the `i` twice which is what you didn't mean. Moreover this will result in **undefined behavior**.

Comment: with `SQR(X) (X*X)` or even `SQR(X) ((X)*(X))` the problem is a little trickier, since `X` can be a side-effect expression or a function, and calling it twice may give unexpected results.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: Yes that's why I am writing and putting it in a later edit otherwise it will be interpreted wrong way

Comment: looks very much like there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719150/square-of-a-number-being-defined-using-define

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: I am writing. Yes it is problem when `SQR(i++)` that is expanded twice.

Answer (score 1):

the define doesn't create a single value 22 but the expression 21 + 1. I wonder whether your problems go away if you change your second #define to
 #define NBRF1 (NBRF + 1)